# Retrieving firebase real time data with Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm storing data in a Firebase realtime database and I'm trying to get the stored data and it seems I'm not getting it correctly - I need any assistance.

`auth.service.ts`:

```
 get_Data() {
  return firebase.database().ref('transfer/').on('value', (snapshot) => {
    this.transfer = snapshot.val();
     console.log('snapshot here',  this.transfer);
  })
 }
```

returns

[image: snapshot here]

`app.component.ts`:

```
 dataList(){
       this.list = this.authService.get_Data();
       console.log('got you', this.list)
    }
```

returning `undefined` ...

Comment: Please check my repo using real-time data from Firebase in React https://github.com/progamandoconro/Firebase-Real-Time-Web-Admin-App, it may help to sollve the issue.

Comment: that's great  @programandoconro, I don't kinda know React but I saw this in your code  

```useEffect(() => {
  db().ref('/').on('value', handleReservas);
  db().ref('/').on('value', handleData)
 }, [userID]);``` kindly elaborate a bit comparing to mine code

Comment: I am happy it helped you. It is more elaborated because I am managing the states of the data, so I can share it in through the App.

Comment: Have you installed angularfire dependency?

Comment: i think that's kinda exactly I'm doing with service In Angular, but im not still not getting it up

Comment: yes @Chellappanவ ,
 ``` import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';``
```import { Router } from "@angular/router";```
```import * as firebase from 'firebase';```

Comment: @Chellappanவ so the issues here is pushing the data to different component and display up

Comment: Can you check this: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md

Comment: yes @PeterHaddad that's was great exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
 get_Data() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     firebase.database().ref('transfer/').on('value', (snapshot) => {
     this.transfer = snapshot.val();
     resolve(snapshot.val());
     console.log('snapshot here',  this.transfer);
   });
  });
 }
```

Then inside your component, you can do:

```
 dataList(){
       this.authService.get_Data().then((value) => {
       console.log(value);
        });
    }
```

Check here for more info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then